# Sending an URL alongside text using WhatsApp URL scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, whatsapp

I'm trying to send some text accompanied by an URL using WhatsApp's custom URL scheme. There's apparently only one valid parameter for this purpose: `text`:

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
```

The problem comes when I want to append my own URL to that text. I opted to encode it using this:

```
NSString *encodedURLString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                                  NULL,
                                                                                  (CFStringRef)urlAbsoluteString,
                                                                                  NULL,
                                                                                  (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                                  kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ));
```

The URL is sent to WhatsApp alongside the text but it doesn't get decoded on the WhatsApp's side:

[image: WhatsApp not decoding the URL]

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're approaching it correctly, but it appears that the URL is being double-encoded.  Make sure both the message and URL is only encoded once.

Using your same encoding method, you can do something like so:

```
NSString *urlAbsoluteString = @"Hello World! http://yayvisitmysiteplease.com?funky=parameter&stuff";
NSString *encodedURLString = ...
```

That should give you the URL to execute:

```
whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World%21%20http%3A%2F%2Fyayvisitmysiteplease.com%3Ffunky%3Dparameter%26stuff
```

That makes its way into WhatsApp just like you'd expect. (I verified to make double sure.)

Comment: OMG! That was as it! I had a "hidden" `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` call later after the encoding call… OMG… Thank you!!!

Answer (score 10):

This is complete code to send text and URL both in WhatsApp

```
    NSString * msg = @"Application%20Name%20https://itunes.apple.com/YOUR-URL";

    msg = [msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%3A"];
    msg = [msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F"];
    msg = [msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"%3F"];
    msg = [msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%2C"];
    msg = [msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];
    msg = [msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];

    NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",msg];
    NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlWhats];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me, while the accepted answer somehow didn't.

Answer (score 2):

It will work for Share Link on Whats app

```
NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://video...bla..bla.."];
url =    (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef) url, NULL,CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"),kCFStringEncodingUTF8));

NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",url];
NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlWhats];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
 } else {
 // can not share with whats app
}
```